# Remove everything after some characters

Tags: ruby, string, methods

I have two situations:

In the first, I may have a string like:

```
  Posted 03-20-2017 More info Go to Last Post
```

And I may have a string like:

```
  Posted today More info Go to Last Post
```

In both of the situations, I don't want anything from More Info...

I tried using `gsub`,but it doesn't work for both of the situations.  Does anyone have possible solution?

Comment: You should post what you tried with `gsub`.  And can you clarify what part of the string you want to extract?  I think you want "Posted 03-20-2017" or "Posted today".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be relatively easily accomplished by running `split("More info")` on your strings. What that does is breaks the string in to an array like so:

```
new_string  = "Posted today More info Go to Last Post"
new_string = new_string.split("More info")
# becomes ["Posted today ", " Go to Last Post"]
```

What split does is it breaks a string apart in to an array, where each element is what preceded the argument. So if you have `"1,2,3"` then `split(",")` will return `[1, 2, 3]`

So to continue your solution, you can get the posting date like this:

```
new_string[0].strip
```

`.strip` removes spaces at the front or back of a string, so you'll be left with just `"Posted today"`

Comment: You forgot the argument for `split` in your example. Also, it's usually not a good idea to overwrite one string variable with an array. You could just use `string.split(" More info").first`

Comment: @EricDuminil Good catch-I added the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Ruby [sub](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub), which will give you *a copy the first occurrence of pattern substituted for the second argument*.

So it'll take your whole string `"Posted 03-20-2017 More info Go to Last Post"`, will find your pattern and all what comes after `More info...`, and will replace it with the second argument `More info`, that in this case is the same as first (you can use a variable there).

```
"Posted 03-20-2017 More info Go to Last Post".sub /More info.*/, 'More info'
=> "Posted 03-20-2017 More info"
```

Also gsub works in a similar way.

Comment: `/#{"More info"}.+/ == /More info.+/`

Comment: `/More info.+/ == /More info.*/` (?)

Comment: Not working! Somehow, it gives me the same output                                                                        "Posted Yesterday \n                \n                                  More info\n                                \n                Go to Last Post"